# Ubuntu 14.04: "Home" inode on desktop

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, inode

Ubuntu 14.04.5

I have an unwanted icon on my desktop, that opens Nautilus in the home directory.
My home directory has not actually moved to the desktop. Still is in place under /home/myUserName.
Right-click to list the desktop icon properties, shows it is an "inode/directory".
I suspect this accident happened as I had attempted to add lists to the Unity Launcher using the Ubuntu Tweak Tool.  Didn't manage and have now uninstalled it.  But I am left with the icon on my Desktop.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had opted for this in the Ubuntu Tweak tools,accidentally.
This has been answered, see [askubuntu.com/a/267056/15811](https://askubuntu.com/a/267056/15811)

I had not actually removed Tweak tools either.

I guess the question now is, how does tweak add "shortcuts"? are they shortcuts? links? where are they stored?